# Pig: Filter rows conditions

Tags: apache-pig

I want have a pig script to filter rows on different conditions:

```
i2 = GROUP i1 ALL;

i3 = FOREACH i2 GENERATE AVG(i1.user_followers_count) AS avg_user_followers_count,  AVG(i1.avl_user_total_retweets) AS avg_avl_user_total_retweets, AVG(i1.avl_user_total_likes) AS avg_avl_user_total_likes, AVG(i1.avl_user_total_replies) AS avg_avl_user_total_replies, AVG(i1.avl_user_engagements) AS avg_avl_user_engagements;

top = FILTER i1 BY (user_followers_count > i3.avg_user_followers_count) AND (avl_user_engagements > i3.avg_avl_user_engagements) AND (avl_user_total_retweets > i3.avg_avl_user_total_retweets) AND (avl_user_total_likes > i3.avg_avl_user_total_likes) AND (avl_user_total_replies > i3.avl_user_total_replies);

bot = FILTER i1 BY (user_followers_count < i3.avg_user_followers_count) AND (avl_user_engagements < i3.avg_avl_user_engagements) AND (avl_user_total_retweets < i3.avg_avl_user_total_retweets) AND (avl_user_total_likes < i3.avg_avl_user_total_likes) AND (avl_user_total_replies < i3.avl_user_total_replies);
```

That is I am picking everything that is above average in every aspect as `top`, everything that is below average in every aspect as `bottom`.

Now I want to get the remaining rows (that is everything mixed, i.e. few aspects above average and few below average) after filtering `top` and `bot` into another alias called `med`. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SPLIT](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#SPLIT)

```
SPLIT i1 INTO 
   top IF((user_followers_count > i3.avg_user_followers_count) AND (avl_user_engagements > i3.avg_avl_user_engagements) AND (avl_user_total_retweets > i3.avg_avl_user_total_retweets) AND (avl_user_total_likes > i3.avg_avl_user_total_likes) AND (avl_user_total_replies > i3.avl_user_total_replies)),
   bot IF((user_followers_count < i3.avg_user_followers_count) AND (avl_user_engagements < i3.avg_avl_user_engagements) AND (avl_user_total_retweets < i3.avg_avl_user_total_retweets) AND (avl_user_total_likes < i3.avg_avl_user_total_likes) AND (avl_user_total_replies < i3.avl_user_total_replies)),
   med OTHERWISE;
```

Comment: Thanks, Not sure if `OTHERWISE` is correct syntax. I have some records lost when I use this code.

Comment: `Input(s):
Successfully read 165 records (362590 bytes) from: "/user/alenza/virtua/marketanalysis/data/results/analysis_name/tweets_combined/user"`



`Output(s):
Successfully stored 0 records (815 bytes) in: "/tmp/inf_med"
Successfully stored 1 records (163 bytes) in: "/tmp/inf_top"
Successfully stored 113 records (18068 bytes) in: "/tmp/inf_bot"`